# Coturn server - Handling stale-nonce and channel timeouts

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn, ice

Coturn default configuration for stale-nonce and channel timeout looks as below.

```
#stale-nonce=600
#channel-lifetime=600
```

I have my own webrtc client simulator developed in c/c++. In a typical call, with relay candidates selected (actually enforced as per user configuration) as part of connectivity check, Till 10 minutes media works fine. After 10 minutes though media is sent from my simulator, but Coturn not forwarding those media packets to other party.

Here are the detailed sequence of events / analysis I have done so far.

1) At the end of 10 minutes, from simulator I sent channel refresh request using old nonce
2) Coturn sent me 438 response, it indicates new nonce and realm
3) I extracted new nonce and realm
4) I recalculated integrity key
5) I again send refresh request
6) I got refresh success response

Still further media packets sent by my simulator, coturn does not forward to other party in call.

Can somebody please help me to understand what went wrong here, and how can I trouble shoot this issue.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: not exactly. we increased channel lifetime and related configurations. incase you get it please share.

Comment: any update @Austin?